# Windows Azure Table Storage Take Issue

Tags: java, azure-storage

On Windows Azure table Storage I am executing the next query:

```
CloudTableClient ctc=TableStorage.getTableClient();
String q1=TableQuery.generateFilterCondition(TableConstants.PARTITION_KEY, QueryComparisons.EQUAL, Long.toHexString(partitionId));
TableQuery<Actividad> rangeQuery=TableQuery.from(tableName, Actividad.class).where(q1).take(2);
int e=0;
for(Actividad ac:ctc.execute(query)){
    e++;
}
System.out.println(e);
```

But I am getting all rows on partition, not just the top 2 specified on take(2).

Any suggestion?

Answering smarx:

I use Wireshark to see the http requests:

The initial request is:

`GET /actividadreciente?$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20%2717%27&$top=2&timeout=60`

There is a response from the service and then a lot of requests are made:

`GET /actividadreciente? $filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20%2717%27&$top=2&NextRowKey=1%2124%21RkZGRkZFQzY2REYzMTA3Mw--&timeout=60&NextPartitionKey=1%214%21MTc-`

`GET /actividadreciente?$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20%2717%27&$top=2&NextRowKey=1%2124%21RkZGRkZFQzY3Mjk2MEZEOA--&timeout=60&NextPartitionKey=1%214%21MTc-`

`GET /actividadreciente?$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20%2717%27&$top=2&NextRowKey=1%2124%21RkZGRkZFQzY3Mjk5MzVGOQ--&timeout=60&NextPartitionKey=1%214%21MTc-`

And so on.

Comment: What programming language is this written in? What library is it using?

Comment: It is Java. Windows Azure Java SDK.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Have you used Fiddler (or a similar HTTP debugging proxy) to look at the actual traffic from your machine to the storage service? I wonder if the $top parameter is missing, or perhaps if multiple requests are being made (to page through the results). Either could indicate a bug in the library.

Comment: I do it. I edit my question. I suppose it is a library bug. Do you know how can I report it?

Comment: What happens if you don't keep iterating? I think execute() returns an iterator that keeps fetching new pages as long as you request them (by iterating). If you stop reading entities after you get the two you're looking for, my guess is that only one query will be issued.

Answer (score 0):

Smarx is right, one can iterate over all results, but if you only iterate over the first 2, the library will only make a request with those items. Subsequence iterations are made with aditional requests. So the solution is to use the next code:

```
CloudTableClient ctc=TableStorage.getTableClient();
final int limit=2;
String q1=TableQuery.generateFilterCondition(TableConstants.PARTITION_KEY, QueryComparisons.EQUAL, Long.toHexString(partitionId));
TableQuery<Actividad> rangeQuery=TableQuery.from(tableName, Actividad.class).where(q1).take(limit);
int e=0;
for(Actividad ac:ctc.execute(query)){
    e++;
    //Use ac
    if(e==limit)break;
}
System.out.println(e);
```

Thank you a lot Smarx!